# highlight text in autocomplete text box

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a auto complete text box where when I search certain content that particular content should get highlighted for the display.

I'm getting the dropdown menu with the typed content but I couldn't get it highlighted. Can anyone suggest me a way?

Comment: https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/highlight-search-result-angular-filter/

Comment: I appreciate your concern but actually I want to highlight only the text which i enter in the dropdown.

Comment: Could you please provide your code or better if you create plunker?

Comment: <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:content track by $index"ng-style="set_color({{$content}})" ng-click="handleSelection(item[subtitle])" style="cursor:pointer" ng-class="{active:isCurrent($index)}" ng-mouseenter="setCurrent($index)"> 

This is the code is used for fitering the text from my JSON file but i could not make it highlighted...

Answer (score 0):

try angular Typeahead directive https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/